# Dummy blog entries for Wordpress theme development

Tags: wordpress, themes, blogs

I'm developing a custom wordpress blog theme.

Does anyone know if there is a dummy database of entries that I can use for development?

At the moment I'm using live data from my own blog, which is okay, but I've seen themes on the wordpress database that have the same entries using all the different things that appear, forms, styled text, different types of bullets and tables, etc. As far as I could see, that data isn't released.

I know I could just create my own entries to exercise all these cases, but I'm [lazy and impatient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall#Virtues_of_a_programmer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Download a sample content file from here : [Easier Theme Development with Sample WordPress Content](http://wpcandy.com/articles/easier-theme-development-with-the-sample-post-collection.html).

Then import it to your blog (Tools - Import - WordPress).

Answer (score 3):

Wordpress also has a theme development checklist which includes sample content: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development_Checklist

Answer (score 3):

You can download the Wordpress Sample contents here http://wpcandy.s3.amazonaws.com/resources/postsxml.zip.

This is useful to test your wordpress without wasting your time to post a test entries.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using "WP Example Content" plugin. The advantage of this plugin is that you can enable/disable sample contents on demand.